# alsaloop: What happens on a buffer underrun?

Tags: audio, alsa, latency

I am tuning my sound interface latency with

```
alsaloop -C hw:1,0 -P hw:1,0 -t $LATENCY_US
```

When I set `$LATENCY_US` to 30000, I get around 20% CPU usage.

I can restart this a few times and make some noise, and after a few trials I suddenly get 100% CPU usage (most of that spent in the kernel, red in `htop`). Restarting `alsaloop` multiple times then does not help, until I "give it some time" before starting it again - then it is back to normal and I can repeat the whole procedure. Note that alsaloop gives no output here.

**Question 1**: What is happening here?

---

If I set `$LATENCY_US` as low as 4000, CPU usage spikes up to 100% for a second; then alsaloop reports `underrun for playback hw:1,0`, CPU is low and stays so.

**Question 2**: What happens in this case? Why does it *calm down*? Is it still recording with the latency I set after the `underrun`?

Thank you.